# What is wrong with the script to create hash tables based on data stored in XML file dz121.xml

Tags: xml, powershell, hashtable

First I wrote a script that creates a file

```
$xml = [xml]$($processes| Select-Object Name, ID, StartTime, 
    PagedMemorySize | ConvertTo-Xml -Depth 2)
$xml.Save( $( Resolve-Path ./ ).Path + "\dz121.xml" )
```

Now I'm trying to convert the XML file into a hesester.

```
$XMLdata = [xml]$(Get-Content .\dz121.xml) 
$ht = @{}
$XMLdata.ChildNodes | Foreach {$ht[$_.Name] = $_.Value}
$ht
```

That's what I tried to do

Comment: [Edit] the question and explain what you expect to get, and what you actually get. If there are any error messages, include those - as text - too.

Comment: I need to get a hashtable, I get it, but it's empty

Comment: Does the file contain sensible data? How does it look like?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Objects>
  <Object Type="System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject">
    <Property Name="Name" Type="System.String">chrome</Property>
    <Property Name="Id" Type="System.Int32">916</Property>
    <Property Name="StartTime" Type="System.DateTime">24.01.2023 9:17:25</Property>
    <Property Name="PagedMemorySize" Type="System.Int32">225562624</Property>
  </Object>

Answer (score 0):

Your question didn't include the initialization of `$processes`, but based on the XML you provided in the comment, it must have been similar to: `$processes = Get-Process`.

The problem with your hash table is that you're not adding values from the correct depth. This should work instead:

```
$processes = Get-Process

$xml = [xml]$($processes| Select-Object Name, ID, StartTime, PagedMemorySize | ConvertTo-Xml -Depth 2)
$xml.Save("c:\tmp\file.xml")

$XMLdata = [xml]$(Get-Content "c:\tmp\file.xml") 

$ht=@{}

$XMLdata.ChildNodes.Object | foreach {
    $processId = ($_.property | where name -eq id).'#text'
    $ht[$processId] = $_.property
}

#Display Output
$ht.GetEnumerator()
```

Comment: Thank you! This almost works but doesn't read data from the file.                                         Name                           Value
----                           -----
18240                          {Name, Id, StartTime, PagedMemorySize}
17896                          {Name, Id, StartTime, PagedMemorySize}
9276                           {Name, Id, StartTime, PagedMemorySize}

Comment: I used a temp directory and file to simplify the code to demonstrate how to access the object data. I didn't intend to draw attention to that modification. If your earlier code worked with the XML, just put that part back Otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean "it doesn't read data from the file".

Comment: Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.